# Call through 3 freeswitches

Tags: freeswitch

I have 3 FS's. 1st FS always 'connects' to 2nd FS and 2nd FS always 'redirects' to 3rd FS. Could anyone please help me to write down the dialplan code?

I could find the link for call through two FSs

```
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Connect_Two_FreeSWITCH_Boxes
```

Also, call can be initiated at 1st FS only and received at 3rd FS and not other way around. (But RTP packets has to flow both ends)

Comment: Setup a trunk between FS1 and FS2 say Route1, then FS2 and FS3 say Route2. Now bridge the calls through those trunks in dial plan